# Returning duplicates from a DataTable using custom IEqualityComparer

Tags: c#, linq, compare

**Update**: I can find duplicates.
However I was testing duplicates that contained the character: '*'
and it doesn't find them.
Anyone any ideas why? 
Duplicate path that I was trying was: *.exe

I have two datatables. Each datatable has two columns: path and type.
Duplicates is based on the path.

The following is my custom implementation of: IEqualityComparer

```
internal class RuleComparer : IEqualityComparer<DataRow>
{
    #region IEqualityComparer<string> Members
    public bool Equals(DataRow x, DataRow y)
    {
        return (x["path"] as string).ToUpperInvariant().Equals((y["path"] as string).ToUpperInvariant());
    }

    public int GetHashCode(DataRow obj)
    {
        return obj.Field<string>("path").ToUpperInvariant().GetHashCode();
    }
    #endregion
}
```

Here is where I call it:

```
public IEnumerable<string> Duplicates
{
    get
    {
        return (datatable1.AsEnumerable()
            .Intersect(datatable2.AsEnumerable(), new RuleComparer())
            .Select(dupe => dupe.Field<string>("path"))).ToList();
    }
}
```

However no duplicates are ever found. Anyone able to see what I'm doing wrong? In debugging through the code the Equals method is called.

Thanks in advance

Comment: This is probably not the problem but your string logic is really awkward. Use `string.Equals(a, b, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase)`.

Comment: As an aside, you could do it without a custom `IEqualityComparer`: `var dups = datatable1.AsEnumerable().Select(r => r.Field<string>("path")).Intersect(datatable2.AsEnumerable().Select(r => r.Field<string>("path")), StringComparer.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)`

Comment: Actually, what do you mean by "no duplicates are ever found"? What do you want to happen and what happens instead?

Comment: Can you show a small sample which demonstrates the issue? I cannot reproduce it with two DataTables which contain a column `Path` and values like `A`, `a`, `B`. It works with your code and also with my above.

Comment: Closing as unreproducible. This is probably bogus. The bug is not visible in this code.

Comment: Is your data really **CONTAINING DUPLICATES** ???

Comment: The Property Duplicates never contains any data, even when data contains duplicates. I'm expecting the following to return items when duplicates exist.  datatable1.AsEnumerable()
            .Intersect(datatable2.AsEnumerable(), new RuleComparer())
            .Select(dupe => dupe.Field<string>("path"))).ToList()

Comment: Would it be possible to reopen this question as I've explained why it was initially not returning duplicates. The case where a path starts with a '*' is a valid case for me and I need to be able to find duplicates. Thanks

Comment: Post executable code that demonstrates the issue. I really don't know how else to find the problem